# Combine String with Variable Twig

Tags: string, variables, twig

I'm new to twig and i am trying to combine a variable and a string and send it too a function, without much look,

```
{{key "/uploads"|app }}
```

here is code, i've tried

```
{{key ~ "/uploads"|app }}

{{"`key`/uploads"|app }}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a sidenote when use the pipesymbol `|` its called a `filter` not a `function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply add parentheses like this

```
{{ ( key ~ "/uploads" ) |app }}
```